# Android Room Database relationships

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I have created a database in room android with three entities

```
    @Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_name")
    val categoryName: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    val categoryId: Int
)

@Entity(tableName = "quotes")
data class Quote(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "quote")
    val quote: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    val categoryId: Int
)

@Entity(tableName = "favourites")
data class Favourite(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "quote")
    val quote: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_name")
    val categoryName: String,

//    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
//    val date: Long
)
```

Now my question is how do i create relationship between two tables in this example i would like to create relationship between `Category` and `Quote` so that i can order quotes by `categoryId`. Like this sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM quotes INNER JOIN categories ON quotes.category_id = categories.id WHERE categories.id = :categoryId
```

I went through the official documentation but it went over my head , i couldn't figure out how to do it. I don't expect anyone to write code for me what i want is the simplest explanation possible.

P.s It is my first time with Room database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **1 to many** (a single category can have many quotes) you have a POJO where the single is a field embedded using the `@Embedded` annotation and the many is a field that is a List/Array using the @Relation annotation.

Room generates the equivalent of the JOIN query (equivalent) and is fine if you want ALL the related children.

So you want something like:-

```
data class CategoryWithItsQuotes(
    @Embedded
    val category: Category,
    @Relation(
        entity = Quote::class,
        parentColumn = "category_id",
        entityColumn = "category_id"
    )
    val quoteList: List<Quote>
)
```

Along with a function in an `@Dao` annotated interface such as:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id=:category_id")
fun getCategoryWithItsQuotes(category_id: Int): List<CategoryWithItsQuotes>
```

i.e. there is no need for the JOIN as Room builds the method to get the related Quotes, for the Category(s) via queries that it builds and executes based upon the @Relation annotation and hence why the @Transaction.

If a **many-many** relationship (as you probably want for the Category/Favourite) then you have a table (associative/reference/mapping and other names table) that has two columns, one for associating/referencing/mapping a unique row in one of the tables and the other column for associating/referencing/mapping a unique row in the other table. The 2 columns would both make up the primary key (a composite primary key). With Room you then `@Embed` one table and `@Relation` the other table using the `associateBy` parameter to specify the `Junction` (the table and respective columns).

Room (again with it's limitation of retrieving ALL children) allows hierarchical use of such POJO's e.g. you could have POJO:-

```
data class CategoryWithFavourites(
    @Embedded
    val category: Category,
    @Relation(
        entity = Favourite::class,
        parentColumn = "category_name",
        entityColumn = "category_name"
    )
    val favouriteList: List<Favourite>
)
```

and then :-

```
data class QuoteWithCategoryAndFavourite(
    @Embedded
    val quote: Quote,
    @Relation(
        entity = Category::class,
        parentColumn = "category_id",
        entityColumn = "category_id"
    )
    val category: CategoryWithFavourites
)
```

And then have something like:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE id=:id")
fun getSingleQuoteWithCategoryAndFavourites(id: Int): List<QuoteWithCategoryAndFavourite>
```

- Note this is **not the suggested many-many** (which you probably want so that a category can have many favourites and a favourite can have of many categories).

  - as such this would cope with a favourite only ever being associated with a single category.

**HOWEVER**

There is a flaw with your Entities that may well result in unexpected results, that is you are allowing for multiple category_id's that are the same (the id column is the only column that uniquely identifies a category ***see demo***)

**DEMO**

To demonstrate the above (POJO's and function) consider the additional functions in `@Dao` annotated interface **AllDAOs** (one for convenience/brevity):-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(category: Category): Long
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(quote: Quote): Long
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(favourite: Favourite): Long
```

The following `@Database` annotated abstract class:-

```
@Database(entities = [Category::class,Quote::class,Favourite::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if(instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, TheDatabase::class.java, "the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

And the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        /* Add some categories */
        val c1CId = 100;
        val c1Id = dao.insert(Category(categoryName = "CAT1", categoryId = c1CId,id =0))
        val c2CId = 900
        val c2Id = dao.insert(Category(id=0, categoryName = "CAT2", categoryId = c2CId))
        val c3CId=900 /* ouch!!!!!!!!!  same category_id to demonstrate flaw */
        val c3Id = dao.insert(Category(id=0, categoryName = "CAT3", categoryId = c3CId))

        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote001",c1CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote002",c2CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote003",c3CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote004", categoryId = c1CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote005", categoryId = c1CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote006", categoryId = c1CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote007", categoryId = c2CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote008", categoryId = c2CId))
        dao.insert(Quote(id=0, quote = "Quote009", categoryId = c3CId))

        logCatWithQuotes(c1CId)
        logCatWithQuotes(c2CId)
        logCatWithQuotes(c3CId)

    }

    private fun logCatWithQuotes(catid: Int) {
        for(cwq in dao.getCategoryWithItsQuotes(catid)) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (q in cwq.quoteList) {
                sb.append("\n\tQuote is ${q.quote} ID is ${q.id} CATID is ${q.categoryId}")
            }
            Log.d(
                "DBINFO_CAT${catid}",
                "CAT is ${cwq.category.categoryName} ID is ${cwq.category.id} CATID is ${cwq.category.categoryId}. It has ${cwq.quoteList.size} quotes. They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run the result output to the log is:-

```
2023-04-03 11:16:43.016 D/DBINFO_CAT100: CAT is CAT1 ID is 1 CATID is 100. It has 4 quotes. They are:-
        Quote is Quote001 ID is 1 CATID is 100
        Quote is Quote004 ID is 4 CATID is 100
        Quote is Quote005 ID is 5 CATID is 100
        Quote is Quote006 ID is 6 CATID is 100
2023-04-03 11:16:43.020 D/DBINFO_CAT900: CAT is CAT2 ID is 2 CATID is 900. It has 5 quotes. They are:-
        Quote is Quote002 ID is 2 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote003 ID is 3 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote007 ID is 7 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote008 ID is 8 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote009 ID is 9 CATID is 900
2023-04-03 11:16:43.020 D/DBINFO_CAT900: CAT is CAT3 ID is 3 CATID is 900. It has 5 quotes. They are:-
        Quote is Quote002 ID is 2 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote003 ID is 3 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote007 ID is 7 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote008 ID is 8 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote009 ID is 9 CATID is 900
2023-04-03 11:16:43.025 D/DBINFO_CAT900: CAT is CAT2 ID is 2 CATID is 900. It has 5 quotes. They are:-
        Quote is Quote002 ID is 2 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote003 ID is 3 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote007 ID is 7 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote008 ID is 8 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote009 ID is 9 CATID is 900
2023-04-03 11:16:43.025 D/DBINFO_CAT900: CAT is CAT3 ID is 3 CATID is 900. It has 5 quotes. They are:-
        Quote is Quote002 ID is 2 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote003 ID is 3 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote007 ID is 7 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote008 ID is 8 CATID is 900
        Quote is Quote009 ID is 9 CATID is 900
```

First thing is that it appears to be working and certainly demonstrates the answer to the question in regard to handling the relationship (albeit open to misuse).

**i.e. CAT1 is as expected it has the 4 quotes assigned.**

**However, CAT2 and CAT3 have too many quotes and are also repeated**, that is each is the sum of both due to them having the same **non-unique category_id** 900. So:-

- a search for CAT2 via the category_id finds CAT2 and CAT3 and vice-versa and of course the quotes for each will have the same reference and thus reference both.

In short the **id** field/column could do all that is required of the **category_id** field/column and would be unique and thus not result in such an issue. Furthermore there would be a space saving and perhaps an efficiency gain as the category_id column is not needed and in fact a hinderance as has been shown.